# What's the difference between these ways to start/run a Generic Host in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

The hosting design in the ASP.NET Core have a new Generic Host now (.NET Core 2.1+) that will replace the Web Host in the future.

There are a lot of ways to start the application using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` interfaces `IHost` and `IHostBuilder`.

I know the difference between using `async` vs `sync`, but what are the differences between all these options? Using `Run` vs `Start` and calling on `IHostBuilder` vs calling on `IHost`?

See the options `// 1`, `// 2`, `// 3` and `// 4` in the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHostBuilder builder = CreateBuilder();

            // 1 - Call Run on the builder (async)
            await builder.RunConsoleAsync();    // extension method

            // 2 - Call Start on the builder (sync)
            builder.Start();                    // extension method

            IHost host = builder.Build();       // Call Build on the builder to get a host

            // 3 - Call Run on the host (sync / async)
            host.Run();                         // extension method
            await host.RunAsync();              // extension method

            // 4 - Call Start on the host (sync / async)
            host.Start();                       // extension method
            await host.StartAsync();            // class method
        }

        private static IHostBuilder CreateBuilder() => new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                //...
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
                //...
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                //...
                services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyService>();
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> // 1 - Call Run on the builder (async)

RunConsoleAsync enables console support, builds and starts the host, and waits for Ctrl+C/SIGINT or SIGTERM to shut down. So as it's expected from its name it's for hosting your app in console only (not IIS, etc)

> // 2 - Call Start on the builder (sync)

just starts the host synchronously

```
public static IHost Start(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    var host = hostBuilder.Build();
    host.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return host;
}
```

> // 3 - Call Run on the host (sync / async)

RunAsync runs the app and returns a Task that completes when the cancellation token or shutdown is triggered.
Sync is just a wrapper:

```
public static void Run(this IHost host)
{
    host.RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

> // 4 - Call Start on the host (sync / async)

This method is actually starting the program and it's called eventually from any other ways.

Answer (score 59):

Updated for .NET 6.

## Summary

- All these methods, *except for `RunConsoleAsync`*, operate on an `IHost` instance. The ones on `IHostBuilder` simply call `IHost.Build()` and then delegate to the `IHost` methods (e.g. `IHostBuilder.StartAsync()` is equivalent to `IHostBuilder.Build().StartAsync()`).
- **Start** methods start the host and **immediately return**.
- **Run** methods start the host and **wait for it to complete before returning**.
- Synchronous versions are all just wrappers around the actual async implementations (`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`).

## Methods

#### StartAsync

```
Task IHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Starts the host (web application). Task completes once the host is started.

#### Start

```
void Start(this IHost host)
```

Synchronous wrapper to `IHost.StartAync`.

#### RunAsync

```
Task RunAsync(this IHost host, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    using (host)
    {
        await host.StartAsync(token);
        await host.WaitForShutdownAsync(token);
    }
}
```

Starts the host. Task completes when the host shuts down, which can be trigger by cancelling the token or calling `StopAsync()` on another thread.

#### WaitForShutdownAsync

```
Task WaitForShutdownAsync(this IHost host, CancellationToken token = default)
```

Returns a task that completes when the application shuts down. Shutdown is initiated via the passed token, and cancelling the token causes the application to stop.

#### WaitForShutdown

```
void WaitForShutdown(this IHost host)
```

Synchronous wrapper to `IHost.WaitForShutdownAync`.

#### StopAsync

```
Task IHost.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Gracefully stops the host, returning a task that completes once the host has stopped. Cancelling `cancellationToken` indicates stop should no longer be graceful.

There's also an extension method that allows passing a `Timeout` instead:

```
public static Task StopAsync(this IHost host, TimeSpan timeout)
    => host.StopAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(timeout).Token);
```

#### RunConsoleAsync

```
Task RunConsoleAsync(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    => hostBuilder.UseConsoleLifetime().Build().RunAsync(cancellationToken);
```

[*source*](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.5/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L326)

This is the only one that uses `IHostBuilder` (instead of `IHost`) because it invokes `UseConsoleLifetime()` (which needs `IHostBuilder`). This also causes a wait for *Ctrl+C* to exit.

There's also no corresponding **Start** method, which I can only speculate is because the vast majority of time in a console app this is all you'd need. The very few that run other backend services plus ASP.NET would probably be better off using `RunAsync()` and managing lifetime (ie: controlling the `CancellationToken`) themselves.