# Self-hosted ASP.NET Core 6 Web API sample system test return always 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, system-testing

I have a project in [GitHub](https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api) that name is [BSN.IpTables.Api](https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/tree/main/Source/BSN.IpTables.Api)

This project has a simple API as shown here:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IIpTablesSystem ipTables)
    {
        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
        this.ipTables = ipTables;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Response<IpTablesChainSetViewModel>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public IActionResult List()
    {
        return Ok(); // This is just for sample
        return Ok(ipTables.List());
    }

    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;
    private readonly IIpTablesSystem ipTables;
}
```

I try to write system test for this project in [BSN.IpTables.Api.SystemTest](https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/tree/main/Test/SystemTests/BSN.IpTables.Api.SystemTest)

I setup my test project like below

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSetup
{
    // TODO: Move to BSN.Commons
    public static int GetAvailablePort()
    {
        const ushort MIN_PORT = 3000;
        const ushort MAX_PORT = UInt16.MaxValue - 30;

        IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

        HashSet<int> usedPorts = Enumerable.Empty<int>()
            .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Select(c => c.LocalEndPoint.Port))
            .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners().Select(c => c.Port))
            .Concat(ipProperties.GetActiveUdpListeners().Select(c => c.Port))
            .ToHashSet();

        for (int port = MIN_PORT; port <= MAX_PORT; ++port)
        {
            if (!usedPorts.Contains(port)) return port;
        }

        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("This system does not has any port for using int this application");
    }

    public static RestClient CreateRestClient(string serverAddress)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient(serverAddress);
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request: new RestRequest("api"));
        if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
        {
            client = new RestClient(TestSetup.ServerUrl);
            if (client.Execute(request: new RestRequest("api")).ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException($"RestClient does not found server in address {TestSetup.ServerUrl}");
        }

        return client;
    }

    public static RestClient CreateDefaultRestClient()
    {
        return new RestClient($"{TestSetup.ServerUrl}");
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

        var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
        builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(startup.ConfigureContainer);
        builder.WebHost.UseUrls(ServerUrl);

        app = builder.Build();

        startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);

        app.StartAsync().Wait();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        app.StopAsync().Wait();
    }

    public static string ServerUrl
    {
        get;
    } = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_URLS") ?? $"{DEFAULT_SERVERL_URL}:{GetAvailablePort()}";

    public const string DEFAULT_PREFIX_URL = "api/v1";
    private WebApplication app;
    private const string DEFAULT_SERVERL_URL = "http://localhost";
}
```

After that I write simple test like below in [`HomeControllerTest`](https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/blob/main/Test/SystemTests/BSN.IpTables.Api.SystemTest/HomeControllerTest.cs)

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerTest 
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        client = TestSetup.CreateDefaultRestClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public void List_ShouldBeOk()
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{TestSetup.DEFAULT_PREFIX_URL}/{HOME_CONTROLLER_ROUTE_PREFIX}");
        RestResponse response = client.Get(request);
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private RestClient client;
    private const string HOME_CONTROLLER_ROUTE_PREFIX = "Home";
}
```

My problem is when run this test, I got exception, because I got an Http 404 Not Found error, instead of 200 OK.

Am I correctly setup ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in the system test?

Comment: There's at least 2 request executing, in the test and in setup class, so for me I'd use debugger to narrow down where did the exception happen (i.e. which request resulted in 404?) 

Also while you're using debugger, try to set multiple checkpoints to see whether some codes are actually executed during unit test, to make sure the setups are actually ran.

The way you start up the app seems potentially problematic too. Some thread says that `StartAsync()` returns immediately, what if after that when the app is still starting up the test is already being executed?

Comment: [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62898659/16606026) for `StartAsync()`

Comment: I do not understand your point, The error arise on `response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);` and if I check response, I see response from kestrel. in Test Setup, I change `StartAsync()` to `StartAsync().Wait()` and my problem does not change

Comment: I suspect what you really want is to use [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for integration tests. Right now you're testing your test setup, not your application. The docs at  [Integration Tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) explain how to set up and customize a test server for integration tests